# How to solve nginx 53 access forbidden by rule error?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

I am running docker-compose droplet on an ubuntu server via digitalOcean.

I have a registerd domain but I am unable to reach my phpAdmin.

my nginx config for the phpmyadmin:

```
     location /nothinhere {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
              rewrite ^/nothinhere(/.*)$ $1 break;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_pass http://DOCKERIP:8183/;
}
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  mysql:
    build: .
    image: ghcr.io/userName/mysql:1
    command:
      - "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    container_name: dbcontainer
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 1s
      retries: 120
  phpmyadmin:
    build: .
    image: ghcr.io/userName/php:1
    container_name: dev_pma
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: dbcontainer
      PMA_PORT: 3307
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI: https://www.example.com/nothinhere
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8183:80
  server:
    container_name: server
    build: .
    image: ghcr.io/userName/server:1
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
  client:
    build: .
    image: ghcr.io/userName/client:1
    container_name: FE
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    tty: true
volumes:
  db_data:
networks:
  mynetwork:
```

The image for the phpAdmin is `phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin`

All my containers are running on the server but I am unable to get to the admin site.

Containers:

[image]

PhpMyAdmin:
[image]

nginx logs:

```
2022/04/22 20:55:00 [error] 783603#783603: send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 172.17.0.1:53
2022/04/22 20:55:25 [error] 783603#783603: *1 dev_pma could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out)
2022/04/22 21:07:33 [error] 795471#795471: *5 access forbidden by rule,
2022/04/22 21:07:52 [alert] 795471#795471: *2 open socket #11 left in connection 4
2022/04/22 21:07:52 [alert] 795471#795471: aborting
2022/04/22 21:14:40 [error] 796363#796363: *53 access forbidden by rule
```

I dont have any deny/allow rules in my config

EDIT:

I changed my nginx config to:

```
 location /nothinhere {
          proxy_pass http://DOCKERIP:8183/;
 }
```

and now im getting `error:1408F10B:SSL` error which might indicate that my SSL is blocking somethiing.

Comment: first off, please don't use phpmyadmin, get mysql workbench https://www.mysql.com/fr/products/workbench/

Comment: @Loïc You are correct a connection can be established with the workbench which I have done. I want to have a phpmyadmin since I might end up in a scenario where I do not have access to a workbench and need to see the data online.

Comment: First, I would try connecting locally without going through the nginx proxy, http://localhost:8183 and see if that works.

Comment: @Loïc Any particular reason for that suggestion?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch the 266 vulnerabilities as of today ? https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-784/cvssscoremin-0/cvssscoremax-10/Phpmyadmin.html This thing is 25 yrs old and still every week there is a new vulnerability discovered, it is a malware really.
Also it's just bad. No websockets, no ajax, web 1.0 tool. It's the worst way to manage a database, I'd rather use mysql command line client.
I won't say the word that best qualifies phpmyadmin but you know it.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch treid the localhost, same result.